# Can I list hg tags and bookmarks by author?

Tags: tags, mercurial, bookmarks

I'm working on a large shared repository with lots of tags and bookmarks.

I create quite a lot of tags and bookmarks myself, which get rather lost in the noise.

Can I list just the ones that I created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

From `hg help log`:

```
hg log [OPTION]... [FILE]

(...)

-u --user USER [+]       revisions committed by user
```

Of course you can also sort the output by using appropriate output templating of the output. See `hg help templates` for details and limit the revisions by choosing an approriate revset (`hg help revsets`).

Thus combine it:

```
hg log -r"tag() or bookmark()" -u USERNAME
```

Comment: Hmm, this just produces no output, whereas hg tags and hg bookmarks produce rather a lot (in which are some of mine)

Comment: @planetmaker's revset will identify commits that have a bookmark or are a tag made by a user. Maybe you're looking for bookmarks made by you? In which case there isn't a way to answer your question since mercurial doesn't have a concept of a bookmark or a tag being "owned" by a user.

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to search for "head() and bookmark() and user(USERNAME)", which will identify heads made by USERNAME that also have a bookmark pointing at them.

Comment: Yes, a bookmark cannot be owned by a specific person. And the person who created a tag can be different thant the one who created the tagged changeset - however with bookmarks at least that is often the case. If you want to get the commits which *created* a tag, ask for revisions which you made and which modified .hgtags.